# AngularJS "No pending request to flush" while unit testing a controller with a $resource

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for a controller. This controller has a $resource service injected :

```
function controller($scope, Service) {
    Service.get(function(result){
        // do stuff with the result, not relevant here
    }
}
```

The service is defined like this :

```
angular.module('so').factory('Service', ['$resource', service]);
function service($resource) {
    return $resource('/url', null, {
        get: { method: 'POST', params: {}, isArray: false}
    });
}
```

My Jasmine unit test is the following :

```
describe("Controller", function(){
    var $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('so');

        inject(function( _$httpBackend_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });
    it('should have done stuff irrelevant to the question', function() {
        var $injector = angular.injector('so'),
            $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),

        $httpBackend
            .whenPOST('/url')
            .respond ([]);

        // controller needs to be defined here and not in the beforeEach as there
        // are more parameters passed to it, depending on the test
        var controller = $injector.get('$controller')('controller', { "$scope": $scope });

        $httpBackend.flush();

        // then here the actual test resolution, also irrelevant
    });
});
```

I get an error when running the test :

```
Error: No pending request to flush ! in file:///path/to/angular-mock.js (line 1453)
```

I added a console.log() in the callback from Service.get() and indeed, it is not called (everything outside of the callback is of course called). Also tried to add a scope digest if not phased after controller creation in the unit test, as I saw suggested in an other question, with no luck.

I know that I can mock that in some other ways, but using $httpBackend seems the perfect solution for the test : mocking the webserver and the data received.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.16 (can't upgrade to 1.3.*, IE 8 compatibility required). I first used 1.2.13 and updated to check if it would solve the issue, without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was an injection issue that was solved by changing the test from

```
it('should have done stuff irrelevant to the question', function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector('so'),
        $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope'),

    $httpBackend
        .whenPOST('/url')
        .respond ([]);

    // controller needs to be defined here and not in the beforeEach as there
    // are more parameters passed to it, depending on the test
    var controller = $injector.get('$controller')('controller', { "$scope": $scope });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    // then here the actual test resolution, also irrelevant
});
```

To:

```
it('should have done stuff irrelevant to the question', inject(function(Service) {
    // edited lines because they did not change

    var controller = $injector.get('$controller')('controller', { "$scope": $scope, "Service": Service });

    // edited lines because they did not change
}));
```

So basicaly, adding the inject() in the test function and passing the service to the controller "manually".

I found the issue, that's great, but I don't really understand why it doesn't work. Also, I tried this right after finding the solution :

```
it('should have done stuff irrelevant to the question', inject(function() {
    // edited lines because they did not change
    var Service = $injector.get('Service'),

    var controller = $injector.get('$controller')('controller', { "$scope": $scope, "Service": Service });

    // edited lines because they did not change
}));
```

but this fail again, with the same "no pending request" error. I'm guessing that's some sort of racing issue, where my service can't get the proper $httpBackend to be injected when it's created afterwards, but I don't really understand why this occurs. If anybody can enlighten me... I'll be grateful.